# DataView select expression column with char 'A' in string position 6

Tags: c#, linq, select, datatable, dataview

Is it possible to use DataView to select a specific column and the string position of the column data in a DataTable?

Sample: columnA  has a string 12345A789, I like to have all data in position 6=’A’

```
DataView iDataView = new DataView(iDataTable, SELECT_Expression_string, ORDER_BY_Expression_string, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

What will be the SELECT_Expression_string to get all data in columnA with char ‘A’ in position 6?

If not possible; what will be the LINQ statement?

Thank you,
Rune

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a single character wildcard is not supported for the `DataView.RowFilter`.

You may want to try:

### Update

Your comment in @BugFinder answer indicates you're checking the 7th character, not the 6th.

If it's the 7th character you're checking:

```
DataView dv = (from t in iDataTable.AsEnumerable()
               where Regex.IsMatch(t.Field<string>("columnA"), "\\w{6}A\\w*")
               select t).AsDataView();
```

If it's the 6th:

```
DataView dv = (from t in iDataTable.AsEnumerable()
               where Regex.IsMatch(t.Field<string>("columnA"), "\\w{5}A\\w*")
               select t).AsDataView();
```

Comment: "Working", but I get A, B, C; not D (Total letters A,B,C,D). Any suggestion?

Comment: @RBrattas Try the character class [A-D].  See updated answer.

Comment: @Share1er80 I only want A

Comment: @RBrattas Are you sure you examine the 6th character?  I see your comment in BugFinder's answer and you're checking the 7th character? See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var iData = iDataTable.AsEumberable().Where(f => f.columnA.Length > 5 && f.ColumnA[5] == 'A');
```

This will return all items where the columnA data is longer than 5 and where the 6th character is A.  It may still fail if columnA is null. You could add checks for that too

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: I thought as code goes it explains what it does. I will add some verbage

Comment: Working with following changes: iDataView = (from t in iDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                                       where t.Field<string>("ColumnName").Length > 6 && t.Field<string>("TableName")[6] == 'A'
                                       select t).AsDataView();

Answer (score 0):

```
iDataView = (from t in iDataTable.AsEnumerable()
             where t.Field<string>("ColumnName").Length > 6 && t.Field<string>("TableName")[6] == 'A'
             select t).AsDataView();
```

Comment: Some explanation would help.